# Django model objects, admin and javascript files

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a problem with objects in django admin. I have a model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    pay = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=(('PAID', 'PŁATNY'), ('FREE', 'DARMOWY')),
        default='FREE')
    time = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=(('T', 'TAK'), ('N', 'NIE')),
        default='N',
        help_text='Czy wpis ma być wyłączony po jakimś czasie czy bezterminowy')
    days = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    premium_box = models.CharField(
        max_length = 3,
        choices=(('T', 'TAK'), ('N', 'NIE')),
        default='N',
        help_text='Czy wpis ma być wyświetlany w okienku reklamowym')
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length = 2,
        choices=(('1','1'), ('2','2')),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

For now I have 2 group objects: free and premium. How can I use value of those objects in my javascript file? I need something like this:

```
if (GROUP.OBJECT.CATEGORY < 2) {
        $("div > fieldset > div.form-row.field-category1").hide();
        $("div > fieldset > div.form-row.field-subcategory1").hide();
        $("#group").html('<ul><li>- Additional text</li>');
    }
if (GROUP.OBJECT.TIME == 'N') {
    $(SOME.FIELD).hide()
    }
```

Is it possible in Django?

I added this to my admin.py:

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context['groupaa'] = (Group.objects.values('category'))
    return super(SiteAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

When I use console.log(GROUP_OBJECT_CATEGORY) in my js file I get queryset:

```
<QuerySet [{'category': '1'}, {'category': '2'}]>
```

but I can't get category value from this queryset... I wold like to iterate through this queryset in my js file. Something like:

```
for (var i=0; i<=QUERYSET.length; i++) {
    console.log(QUERYSET[i]);  # get 1 and 2 values
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

- You can show or hide different parts of the page using Django
  templates, no need to use JS for that.
- Inset JS code declaring those JS variables directly to your Django
  template like:

`<script>
    var GROUP_OBJECT_CATEGORY = "{{GROUP.OBJECT.CATEGORY}}";
    </script>`

and use `GROUP_OBJECT_CATEGORY` global variable in your JS code.

- Create an endpoint (view) in your Django that will return group object in
  JSON format and check `group` value of that object in your JS:

`$.getJSON( "/api/get_object", function( object ) {
       if(object.group && object.group < 2 ){
          ....
       }
    });`

Comment: It is too difficult for me... Where should I initiate GROUP.OBJECT.CATEGORY ? I tried add something like group = Group.objects.values('category') to my admin.py and use group in var GROUP_OBJECT_CATEGORY but it doesn't work. In my tradictional views (not admin) it works. I added group = Group.objects.values('category')
    context['group'] = group to my view and console.log(GROUP_OBJECT_CATEGORY) to my js file. It displays GROUP_OBJECT_CATEGORY. I don't know how can I do the same in my admin view.